# Add attachment to email using action Mailer - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have book model which has title, page_no and description. There is another model Image.

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :images, dependent: :destroy
end 

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
end
```

I have used paperclips to upload the images.I need to create a button in book's show page which should send all the book's attributes along with images in email.For this I have configured the action mailer as:

```
rails g mailer BookMailer
```

and created `app/views/book_mailer/booklist_email.html.erb`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to Student Library</h1>
    <p>
      Book: <%= @book.title %>
    </p>
    <p>
      Page Number: <%= @book.page_number %>
    </p>
    <p>
      Description <%= @book.description %>
    </p>
    <p>
      Active <%= @book.active %>
    </p>
    <p>
      Please visit us again !!
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also I placed button in book's show page as(views/books/show.html.erb)

```
<%= content_tag(:button, "Send Email", :type=>:submit)%>
```

booklist_email.html.erb

```
class BookMailer < ApplicationMailer
    default from: "unauthorized.testing@gmail.com"

    def booklist_email(book, email_id_to)
        @book = book
        mail(to: email_id_to, subject: 'List of Books with Images')
    end
end
```

Now how should I trigger the email after clicking button from book show pages which should send email to any user where email should be given at the time of pressing send email button from book show page. Let me know if I need to provide more information. I am confused how should I proceed. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You first need to create a method in `BookMailer` if it's not already there, with all the parameters you want to send to the user:

```
class BookMailer < ActiveMailer::Base
  def booklist_email(email, title)
    mail(from: 'me@me.com', to: email, subject: title)
  end
```

Then to actually deliver the mail:

```
BookMailer.booklist_email(@user.email, 'Hello customer!').deliver
```

Comment: I have already this method, but how should I trigger the email from button which I put in book show page ? I need to understand which controller I refer in button or method so that it trigger the email

Comment: You can call the method above (the one with `deliver`) from any controller action.

You could have a form with a button inside called `send email`, that would call a controller action (say `send_email_to_client`) and in there you use the code from above.

Comment: Why I need form here, I just need to pick up the data from database and deliver in email, am I right ? or you can update your answer accordingly for better understanding

Comment: Absolutely, you can. But since you talked about a button and a show page, you will need a controller at some point.

Comment: The requirement is to put the button on book's show page from there I need to trigger the email, once I click button it should ask for email to enter, I am not sure where I should get the page for asking email as well.

Comment: You'll need a form to send the button then, see my first comment. From there (the controller's action), you'll be able to send the email via the Mailer.